# Change UIImage overlay color efficiently, based on 20 Hz input signal

Tags: ios, bluetooth, uiimage

My app connects to a BLE device which sends signals to the app every 50ms. Based on each signal, I want to change the overlay color of 38 images (could be about 60 in the future).

The **issue** is that **using a standard context to set the overlay color is very heavy in terms of CPU usage, thus making the app non usable**.
Any suggestions on how to really efficiently change the overlay color of an image, will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending sometime playing with different background queue configurations, it all adds up to this: no matter what you do, CPU time has to be used to make the overlay drawing itself. No matter which thread you might assign the drawing to (although, the main thread is the only option), CPU time will be consumed.

For what it is worth, I created a font using the svg images and used UILabels to render. In this context, you only need to set the textColor of the label (a very cheap operation) rather than having to create a context in order to change the colour of an image.